# Must I create a tunnel to access a docker container on another host?

Tags: docker, vagrant, development-environment

On an Ubuntu Host running CoreOS under Vagrant, I have a docker container running nginx on port 80.

```
docker run -v /home/core/share:/var/www:rw -p 80:80 -d nginx-example
```

The Ubuntu host's IP is 192.168.2.2 on the local LAN

On the Ubuntu Host, I can browse to http://172.17.8.101/ and view the webpage served by the nginx container.

If I want to be able to browse to the same webpage from another machine on the LAN, do I need to create an SSH tunnel or is there some other mechanism which would facilitate this? I know that 172.17.8.101 is in a private network range but am not sure how to connect to it from the LAN. Would it be easier to have coreos use an IP in the 192.168 range?

docker inspect:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "docker0",
        "Gateway": "10.1.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "10.1.0.12",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "fe80::42:aff:fe1:c",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:01:00:0c",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

`ifconfig` from coreos :

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.42.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::d81e:ceff:fee7:f6ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b2:d5:75:c1:88:94  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46089  bytes 1871717 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91776  bytes 81647104 (77.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe0d:b324  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:0d:b3:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 332980  bytes 285337617 (272.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 172343  bytes 9961980 (9.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.8.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.17.8.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:9f09  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:d1:9f:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 114  bytes 34912 (34.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93  bytes 10008 (9.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is not a production system - it is simply a home experiment in pursuit of learning more about docker

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker manages its own internal network for the containers.

A straightforward solution might be setting up the mapped ports via Vagrant and having your other machines connect to the host (and get passed through to the Docker guests).

Alternatively, Docker does support a `--net=host` option, to allow the containers to connect to the outside world directly through the host's interfaces, but then you lose the "docker-ness" of things.

If you wanted to build a more robust solution, you could [set up the Docker networking manually](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) and achieve some kind of NAT gateway to the host's LAN.

Comment: Thanks. I think this answer could be improved by referencing all layers involved - host OS (Ubuntu), CoreOS guest and the virtual networks created by both Vagrant AND Docker. With hindsight, I think the question is probably more about Vagrant's virtual networking than Docker's